# How to compress images in kotlin using new android library?

Tags: android, kotlin

This was the old file

```
 if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val resultUri = result.uri
            var userId = mCurrentUser?.uid
            var thumbFile = File(resultUri.path.toString())
            Log.i(result.toString(),"result")
            Log.i(resultUri.toString(),"result Uri")
            Log.i(thumbFile.toString(),"Thumb File")

            var thumbBitMap = Compressor(this)
                .setMaxHeight(200)
                .setMaxWidth(200)
                .setQuality(65)
                .compressToBitmap(thumbFile)


            //upload this image to firebase
            var byteArray = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            thumbBitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArray)
            var thumbByteArray:ByteArray
            thumbByteArray = byteArray.toByteArray()
```

But now it has changed to Compressor.compress and it is asking to be only called from a coroutine
What should be the it now?

Comment: The documentation it's pretty easy: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor#calling-compressor-should-be-done-from-coroutines-scope
You just need to add Coroutines to your project: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#gradle-kotlin-dsl

Comment: @MatPag yes I have implemented that but I am new this so I don't know how to use it in this case.Could you help please?